# set value in select2 as $('#id').val(value);

Tags: jquery-select2

Is there a method to set the value in select2?

We use this method to set the value: `$('#id').val(value);`

Comment: try like this $('#id').val(value).trigger('change'); working link https://jsfiddle.net/kalai6095/vk2x6ac3/ for futher ref: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this

```
$('#id').val(value).trigger('change');
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kalai6095/vk2x6ac3/)